# valid-url not accessible from @heroku-cli/plugin-buildpacks

Tags: node.js, heroku, npm, node-modules, heroku-cli

This is the error I am getting constantly while trying to upload my app to Heroku no wonder what I am doing wrong.

I have updated node_modules reinstalled them
have cli installed and running in vs code.

```
npm ERR! valid-url not accessible from @heroku-cli/plugin-buildpacks
remote:
remote:        npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
remote:        npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.Zudji/_logs/2021-10-11T07_16_45_740Z-debug.log
```

[image: this is the error i am getting]

**UPDATE -**

little update! actually what was happening is i was missing the npm version and node version in pakage.json i added them in my package.json file but somehow it was not getting updated in the git repository even after several commits so what i did is i used: git push -f origin master. To force push it in the repository and as soon as it gets updated Heroku started reading it and the build succeeded thanks for the help though.

Answer (score -1):

little update! actually what was happening is i was missing the npm version and node version in pakage.json i added them in my package.json file but somehow it was not getting updated in the git repository even after several commits so what i did is i used: git push -f origin master. To force push it in the repository and as soon as it gets updated heroku startedn reading it and the build succeeded thaks for the help though.:sparkles: :sparkles: :sparkles: :sparkles: :sparkles: :sparkles:

Comment: Hello! I think it would be more helpful if you used some formatting in your answer, so others could clearly see what is code, period and sentences.